# Settings.canDrawOverlays() calls Package manager has died. Caused by android.os.DeadObjectException

Tags: java, android, exception

I gets this exception only on Android 6.0 - 6.0.1 on different devices.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died
       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackagesForUid(ApplicationPackageManager.java:632)
       at android.provider.Settings.getPackageNameForUid(Settings.java:14462)
       at android.provider.Settings.canDrawOverlays(Settings.java:1569)
       at com.myproject.project.services.MyService.removeicon(MyService.java:240)
       at com.myproject.project.services.MyService.access$200(MyService.java:57)
       at com.myproject.project.services.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:232)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by android.os.DeadObjectException
       at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Binder.java)
       at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
       at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getPackagesForUid(IPackageManager.java:3746)
       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackagesForUid(ApplicationPackageManager.java:630)
       at android.provider.Settings.getPackageNameForUid(Settings.java:14462)
       at android.provider.Settings.canDrawOverlays(Settings.java:1569)
       at com.myproject.project.services.MyService.removeicon(MyService.java:240)
       at com.myproject.project.services.MyService.access$200(MyService.java:57)
       at com.myproject.project.services.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:232)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I have idea that this happens because I use Settings.canDrawOverlays(this) instead of Settings.canDrawOverlays(getApplicationContext()) but I'm not sure. I never faced with DeadObjectException before. Could you please explain when I can catch this exception and how I can avoid this exception. Thanks.

Comment: "can I avoid this exception" -- probably not. If the error message is true, something crashed in the system. "when I can catch this exception" -- wrap your call to `canDrawOverlays()` in a `try`/`catch` block.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the help!